# unable to get manage_pages and publish_pages after app has passed the review

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook app  passed review and it is showing verification is complete for `publish_pages` and `manage_pages` as below screenshot.
[manage_pages and publish_pages were granted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zemAN.png)

But when i try to login, it is not showing permissions page and it is showing error as below.
[Error while logging in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxUHr.png)
Please help.

Comment: This does NOT look like these permissions are actually approved yet - they should have a _green_ circle, if they were. A yellow circle with status saying “complete verif[ication]” means _you_ still have stuff to complete.

Comment: @04FS, Thank you for the reply. Yes you are right. circle is yellow. I have to do business or individual verification. so after I'm done with business or indivudual verification, will i get manage_pages and publish_pages and intermediate screen asking for permissions? Please clarify.

Comment: You will get them, once you successfully complete the review process, and Facebook has approved of what you are trying to do with them.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. please write this as an answer so that i can mark it as solved. in comments i dont have enough points to upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This does NOT look like these permissions are actually approved yet - they should have a *green* circle, if they were.

A yellow circle with status saying “complete verif[ication]” means you still have stuff to complete.

---

You will be able to ask normal users for them, once you successfully complete the review process, and Facebook has approved of what you are trying to do with them.